# How to mirror remote external drive via file sharing in macOS?

Tags: macos, nas, file-sharing, nvme

I am trying to use an old iMac and NVMEs as a NAS and have it act as a local Google Drive on my Wi-Fi network.

The plan is as follows:

1. Get dual NVME enclosure and set it up as a RAID 1 drive on disk utility on my iMac.
2. Turn on file sharing on my iMac and allow my mbp to read/write files to the iMac's external RAID 1 drive.

How do I set up a "virtual" drive on my MacBook Pro to mirror the one connected to my iMac?

I don’t know if this idea is feasible because I don’t know how merging updates from the iMac and the virtual drive on the MacBook Pro will work.

Comment: “How do I set up a "virtual" drive on my MacBook Pro to mirror the one connected to my iMac?” I would recommend using software like [SuperDuper!](https://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) or [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) to mirror the drives.

Comment: Are you asking how to mount the shared drive on your MBP? Like "I've set up my iMac to be a file server on my network, but how do I tell my MBP to connect to it and use it?"? If so, the answer is Finder > Go > Connect to Server.

Comment: IMO, you shouldn’t mirror. All of the solutions are really just making copies, not a real time sync like G-drive or OneDrive would do. Besides, then you’d be writing files to your “slow” MBP and not the RAID (except layer thru the mirror operation).  MBP performance will be as slow as it every was, although your mirror/backup will run fast. Just mount the iMac’s drive on MBP. If you want something a little more seamless, look into setting up the RAID as an NFS share, but that’s getting a little advanced.

Comment: "Just mount the iMac’s drive on MBP" ya honestly might just do this. Easy, fast, and simple.